# Magento 2 load data from customer in custom_attribute field in Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer, custom-attributes

How get data from a customer in custom_attribute fields in the Magento2 Checkout?

I need to load customAttributes from customer if is logged in into this custom_attributes input texts

The LayoutProcessor get the custom_attributes, I need to put in a value of this input texts the data from the Customer (custom attributes).

Any ideas?

Comment: Solved the issue.  
I created a custom Helper for the module and bring customer data via session (customer logged in), loaded data by Email and get all customer attributes.

Comment: can u post code here

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. I created a custom Helper for the module and bring customer data via session (customer logged in), loaded data by Email and get all customer attributes.

Create a Helper in your module and by Constructor inyection put Customer Session class.

```
public function getCustomer()
{

    try {
        $session = $this->session->getCustomer();
        $customerData = null;
        $customData = null;

        if ($session !== null && $session->getEmail() !==null) {
            $this->customer->setWebsiteId($this->store->getStore()->getId()); //                
            $customerData = $this->customer->loadByEmail($session->getEmail());
            if ($customerData !== null) {                 
                $customData = $this->customerRepo->getById($customerData->getId());              
            }
        }

        return $customData;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

After this code, create a inyection and function in your custom LayoutProcessor.

```
public function getCustomerData()
    {
        $data = [];
        $data['direccion'] = '';
        $data['rut'] = '';
        $data['giro'] = '';
        $data['razon'] = '';
        $customer = $this->helper->getCustomer();

        if ($customer !== null) {
            //$this->_log()->info("Customer data cargado.");
            if ($customer->getCustomAttribute('customer_rut') !== null) {
                $data['rut'] = $customer->getCustomAttribute('customer_rut')->getValue();
            }

            if ($customer->getCustomAttribute('customer_razon') !== null) {
                $data['razon'] = $customer->getCustomAttribute('customer_razon')->getValue();
            }

            if ($customer->getCustomAttribute('customer_giro') !== null) {
                $data['giro'] = $customer->getCustomAttribute('customer_giro')->getValue();
            }

            if ($customer->getCustomAttribute('customer_direccion') !== null) {
                $data['direccion'] = $customer->getCustomAttribute('customer_direccion')->getValue();
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return null;
    }
```